# How to determine multiple time-periods present in a waveform using findpeaks() in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, time-series, signal-processing

I'm trying to determine the different time-periods present in a waveform (shown below) using `findpeaks()`.
[image]

The dataset for which I'm finding the peaks and eventually time-period, is an Autocorrelation Plot (though it could have been any given plot). *I generated it using the following code (which you can use as it is for your reference):*

```
import json
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import pickle

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, acf, pacf
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, square
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#GENERATION OF A FUNCTION WITH DUAL SEASONALITY & NOISE

def white_noise(mu, sigma, num_pts):
    """ Function to generate Gaussian Normal Noise
    Args:
        sigma: std value
        num_pts: no of points
        mu: mean value

    Returns:
        generated Gaussian Normal Noise
    """
    
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, num_pts)
    return noise

def signal_line_plot(input_signal: pd.Series, title: str = "", y_label: str = "Signal"):
    """ Function to plot a time series signal
    Args:
        input_signal: time series signal that you want to plot
        title: title on plot
        y_label: label of the signal being plotted
        
    Returns:
        signal plot
    """
    
    plt.plot(input_signal)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.show()

t_week = np.linspace(1,480, 480)
t_weekend=np.linspace(1,192,192)
T=96 #Time Period
x_weekday = 10*square(2*np.pi*t_week/T, duty=0.7)+10 + white_noise(0, 1,480)
x_weekend = 2*square(2*np.pi*t_weekend/T, duty=0.7)+2 + white_noise(0,1,192)
x_daily_weekly = np.concatenate((x_weekday, x_weekend)) 
x_daily_weekly_long = np.concatenate((x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly,x_daily_weekly))
signal_line_plot(x_daily_weekly_long)
signal_line_plot(x_daily_weekly_long[0:1000])

#x_daily_weekly_long is the final waveform on which I'm carrying out Autocorrelation

#PERFORMING AUTOCORRELATION:
import scipy.signal as signal

autocorr = signal.correlate(x_daily_weekly_long, x_daily_weekly_long, mode = "same")
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(x_daily_weekly_long), len(x_daily_weekly_long), mode = "same")

#VISUALIZATION:
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(40)
f.set_figheight(10)
plt.plot(lags, autocorr)
```

My approach to determining the time-period is as follows:

```
#1) Finding peak indices
indices = find_peaks(autocorr.flatten())[0]

#2) Determining Period
diff = [(indices[i - 1] - x) for i, x in enumerate(indices)][1:]
short_period = abs(np.mean(diff))/fs
short_period #is the distance between all the individual peaks.
```

**In this way, I'm able to only find the time-period (distance) between individual peaks. But my need is to determine the time-period for all the multiple periods that the data may contain.**

Can anyone please help, how to determine all possible time-periods present in the data?

Comment: @mozway would you be able to answer this one? This is my broader objective - to determine the presence of any number of periodicities in a waveform. The reason why I'm using Autocorrelation is to simplify the original dataset, after which I can find the distance between peaks and hence the periodicities present. In this case, there maybe only 2 periodicities. But I would like to have a generalized approach where even 3 or more periodicities can also be determined. Any other technique apart from using Autocorrelation is also more than welcome.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco would you be able to answer this one? This is my broader objective.